# Create a syntactical prefix command

Tags: macros

How can I create a new command, whose syntax is likely the `\sffamily` or `\ttfamily` command. For example:

```
{\mycommand xxxxx}
```

Background-information: the Option `font=` of TikZ Node does not allow commands like `\mycommand{}`. This works fine:

```
\tikzstyle{JSToken} = [shape=rounded rectangle,font={\ttfamily}]
```

But this does not work

```
\tikzstyle{JSToken} = [shape=rounded rectangle,font={\texttt}]
```

And I need a command `\myfancyformat` to customized text format of a class of nodes, so that I can use it in this form:

```
{\myfancyformat Stupid Text needs Fancy Format}
```

It has the same syntax as `\sffamily`:

```
{\sffamily Some Sans Serif formated Text}
```

I hope I can espress my idea.

Comment: That would depend on the command you want to implement. Can you give an example of it?  (BTW: `\texttt{something}` is not completely equivalent to `{\ttfamily something}`. Try to add a `\par`...)

Comment: Also, the `tikzstyle` command is deprecated. Use `\tikzset{JSToken/.style= ...}` instead.

Comment: `\ttfamily` is the basic command, `\texttt` with an argument is essentially defined as `\newcommand\texttt[1]{{\ttfamily #1}}`  so you do not do anything special to define a command with no argument.

Comment: I need to define my own command with the same syntax as `\ttfamily`, for example `{\mycommand mytext}`

Comment: @lazyboy And what is `\mycommand` supposed to do? This is essential information, lacking which no answer can be given.

Comment: `\newcommand\mycommand{...}` where `...` could be whatever allowed in the `font` option`. But as said, some clue of what is your real goal will be fine.

Comment: It is more about syntax than semantic, the `\mycommand` my colorized text, bold the text, or what ever It should do. So I can change the format at the time I need.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `\newcommand\mycommand\ttfamily` or `\newcommand\mycommand\sffamily` or `\newcommand\mycommand\bfseries` or `\newcommand\mycommand{\color{blue}}` would all work.  But you probably could have figured that out.  So are you looking for something else?  In that case, you'll probably have to tell us.

Answer (score 1):

If a control sequence `\foo` has usage `{\foo something}` then it is almost certainly a macro without parameter which typically expands to a set of internal settings of TeX registers and/or font selection. TeX has internal registers, their value influences internal TeX algorithms: width of paragraph, baselineskip size, etc. The `{` is group begin and `}` is group end in this case and the settings of registers or font selection is local in this group. It means that the previous parameters values are restored when the group ends, i.e at `}`.

If a control sequence `\foo` has usage `\foo{something}` then it is almost certainly a macro with a single parameter (defined by `\def\foo#1{body}`) and it expands to `body` where its parameter is formally marked as `#1` and it can be used by commands in `body` in any way. Note that the `{` and `}` in the context `\foo{something}` are not begin/end group in this case, but their are only parameter delimiters. They play another role here. TeX is context-dependent interpreter.

If you have a macro `\foo` without parameter with the usage `{\foo something}`, then you can define a new macro `\newfoo` with the syntax `\newfoo{something}` like this:

```
\def\newfoo#1{{\foo #1}}
```

Note that the first `{` here opens the body of the macro (it is a part of the syntax rule when `\def` TeX primitive is used) and the second `{` opens a group when `\newfoo` is expanded. Then `\foo` sets some TeX parameters, then a parameter `#1` is printed and then the group is closed due to the first `}`. The second `}` is a part of a syntax rule of `\def` primitive.

The reverse way: from `\foo{something}` syntax to `{\newfoo something}` syntax is sometimes possible, but it is more tricky and you have one more group begin/end than if pure `\foo{something}` is used:

```
\def\newfooA#1{\foo{#1}\egroup}
\def\newfoo{\expandafter\newfooA\expandafter{\iffalse}\fi}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the false idea that the syntax of `\ttfamily` includes braces. It does not, it simply changes the font at that point, just as `\color{red}` changes the color at that point or `\large` changes the font size at that point.

So there is nothing special you need to do about the syntax: if you define

```
\newcommand\mycommand{\color{red}\large\ttfamily}
```

it will make large red monospace with the required syntax.